# gwtprojsonserializer 1.0.4 jar - error serializing arraylist

Tags: json, gwt, serialization

I am using gwtprojsonserializer to convert objects to JSON. I've added the version 1.0.4 jar I downloaded from the website http://code.google.com/p/gwtprojsonserializer/ but although the source code on the website includes functionality for serializing arraylists, it is not included in the jar and hence i get the following error:

com.kfuntak.gwt.json.serialization.client.SerializationException: Can't find object serializer for java.util.ArrayList

Does anyone know how I can update the jar or use their latest source code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Its open source project. The entire source code can be easily downloaded from http://code.google.com/p/gwtprojsonserializer/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

I am assuming the required code for serializing arraylists is in trunk. You can add/remove/modify on you local copy. Build the jar ( it just requires **mvn clean install** command)

If you are having local repository, use **mvn deploy**. Ensure your version id is different to avoid confusion.